# Mixed Triangular and Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions

I am looking for a way to produce a probability density function that is a "blend" between a binomial distribution and a triangular distribution. The scenario I wish to model is based around a minimum and maximum cost for an event or piece of work, with a risk-likelihood probability of maximum cost influencing the peak of a triangular distribution between the two. Logically, then, at 0% risk-likelihood, the PDF should return only values at the minimum, and at 100% should return only values at the maximum. At 50%, the PDF should be a triangular distribution, with the peak at the midpoint of the two costs. However, using a triangular distribution has shown to inflate the tails, as is evident in using a triangular distribution of, e.g., 0% risk-likelihood (min, min, max). The resultant PDF is a right-angled triangle, rather than a single peak at the minimum, as is expected. Is there a way to influence a triangular distribution to contain this exponential decay as it moves away from the 50%-ile? I have attached a sketch below of an example - the R function dTriBin from the "fitODBOD" package uses a beta function to form the union of a triangular and binomial, so I expect this may have some role in this, but the results from this function were not in line with what is needed from this line of inquiry.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Example sketch of desired function output with changing peak percentile]

Answer (score 1):

Ended up stumbling across the distribution, logging it here in case anybody has the same issue in future. It's called a PERT, GIF below.

[image: PERT distribution changing with peak shift]